# Connection of computer to monitor

Tags: display, cable

I have at home 2 computers and 2 monitor screens.
I'd like the newer computer to be connected to the newer screen, and the older computer to the older one.
However, the older screen does not seem to recognize the older computer.
If I connect the older computer to the newer screen, it works fine.
If I connect the newer computer to the older screen, it also works fine.
The same cable is used in every case.

What else can I check? What could be the problem?

Comment: What king of cable is it ? VGA ?

Comment: What do you mean "the older screen does not seem to recognize the older computer"?

Comment: on the old computer try setting the screen resolution to 800 by 600 for the purpose of testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a resolution problem.
Check the resolution of your old PC by connecting the new monitor and see if it is within the range of your old monitor.

Comment: makes sense. Will try when I get home